# remove '\0' remove character from string array in c language and put instead replace it space ascii code

Tags: c

Bit Fields in C
In C, we can specify size (in bits) of structure and union members. The idea is to use memory efficiently when we know that the value of a field or group of fields will never exceed a limit or is within a small range.
If storage is limited, we can go for bit-field.
A special unnamed bit field of size 0 is used to force alignment on next boundary. For example consider the following program.
For example, consider the following declaration of date without the use of bit fields.
i can have pointers to 5-bit bit field members as they may not start at a byte boundary but i can new pointer structure assign to address of end of last bit only.
i am declare 5 bit ascii code.
please see my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
// Space optimized representation of the date
struct date {
    // d has value between 0 and 31, so 5 bits
    // are sufficient
    int d : 5;
 
    // m has value between 0 and 15, so 4 bits
    // are sufficient
    int m : 4;
 
    int y;
};
 
int main()
{
    printf("Size of date is %lu bytes\n",
           sizeof(struct date));
    struct date dt = { 31, 12, 2014 };
    printf("Date is %d/%d/%d", dt.d, dt.m, dt.y);
    return 0;
}
```

```
Output: 

Size of date is 8 bytes
Date is -1/-4/2014
```

The output comes out to be negative. What happened behind is that the value 31 was stored in 5 bit signed integer which is equal to 11111. The MSB is a 1, so it’s a negative number and you need to calculate the 2’s complement of the binary number to get its actual value which is what is done internally. By calculating 2’s complement you will arrive at the value 00001 which is equivalent to decimal number 1 and since it was a negative number you get a -1. A similar thing happens to 12 in which case you get 4-bit representation as 1100 which on calculating 2’s complement you get the value of -4.
above code tell me my code and solution is correct?
we can replace '\0' character and add space ascii code .
i can use 5-bit instead 8-bit or 7-bit ascii code if my storage is very low.
but in this situation i can used pointer for it.but problem is unsign and address in memory is sign .we can use sign address and tag it by last-bit and convert it to hex .
please tell me my solution is correct or not?

Comment: Why did you tag c++ and python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int d : 5` allows you to represent values between `-16` and `15`, not between `0` and `31`.

`int m : 4` allows you to represent values between `-8` and `7`, not between `0` and `15`.

You need to use `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: Per C 2018 6.7.2 5, it is implementation-defined whether `int` in a bit-field declaration designates `signed int` or `unsigned int`. So `int d : 5` may represent −16 to 15 or 0 to 31 (or −15 to 15 in case of one’s complement or sign-and-magnitude).

Comment: we can replace '\0' character and add space ascii code . i can use 5-bit instead 8-bit or 7-bit ascii code if my storage is very low. but in this situation i can used pointer for it.but problem is unsign and address in memory is sign .we can use sign address and tag it by last-bit and convert it to hex . please tell me my solution is correct or not?

Comment: @saeedbahmanabadi I don't see any part of the solution to your problem having anything to do with "replacing `\0`".  The solution is to switch to an `unsigned` bitfield, as bbbbbbbbb said.  The `unsigned` keyword affects how the *value* of the bitfield is interpreted.  It has nothing to do with the address.